# How can I redirect the user after updating state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, react-hooks

I have a React login page that calls a NodeJS API for authentication (by Axios). This seems to work fine. It returns true when successful and an error message on failure. Ps: I'm not using JWT but session instead. I wanna that after login successfully, a state (global) in the component change and then redirects the user to the dashboard.

The code that I have seems to change the global state (Redux) with no problem on tests I made after login successfully.

```
export const Login = () => {

    const loggedIn = useSelector(state => state.loggedIn)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const axiosURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:3333'

    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState("")
    const [returnMessage, setReturnMessage] = useState("")

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {

        e.preventDefault()

        setTimeout(async (e) => {

            const { data } = await axios.post( axiosURL + '/login', inputs)

            setReturnMessage(data.message)

            if (!data.message) dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN' })

        }, 1000)
    }

    if (loggedIn) {

        return <Redirect to='/' />
    }

    return (... the JSX form code ...)
}
```

This is working and redirects to "/" when the login works, the problem is that I'm getting an error that I don't know how to fix (and the reason):

```
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

The "/" is a protected route and again seems to work fine, when I set the default value for the global state to true the page loads without redirecting the user to "/login". This is the code I have for redirecting the users on private route in case the state is false:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component }) => (

    <Route render={props => (

        loggedIn ? (

            <Component {...props} />

        ) : (

            <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
        )
    )}
    />
)
```

Does anyone know how to fix it or even propose a better solution for what I need? I don't wanna work storing JWT on client side for security purposes. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed that by adding the global state loggedIn as props, like this:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, loggedIn }) => (

    <Route render={props => (

        loggedIn ? (

            <Component {...props} />

        ) : (

            <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
        )
    )}
    />
)
```

And:

```
export const Routes = () => {

    const loggedIn = useSelector(state => state.loggedIn)

    return (
        <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home} loggedIn={loggedIn} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route component={Error404} />
        </Switch>
    )
}
```

If anyone knows a better approach for this, please let me know.